# Can I improve the computation time of my DFS using multithreading in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization

I am writing a program that computes the total amount of unique games of connect 4 that can be played.  To do this I have a DFS like algorithm that iterates through every possibility:

```
void DFS(int col, PositionPiece turn, std::vector<int> plays, Board board) {
  // Place current piece
  if (board.place(col, turn)) {
    plays.push_back(col);

    printf("%s\n", board.toString().c_str());

    // Check for complete game
    if (plays.size() == (MAX_ROW*MAX_COL)) { // Check if board if full
      GAME_COUNTER += 1;
      return;
    }

    if (board.winner() != EMPTY) { // Check if someone won
      GAME_COUNTER += 1;
      return;
    }

  } else {
    return;
  }

  // Place next piece
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_COL; i++) {
    DFS(i, turn, plays, board);
  }
}


for (int firstCol = 0; firstCol < MAX_COL; firstCol++) {
  DFS(firstCol, turn, plays, board);
}
```

The problem is this program is taking way too long to run.  I let it run for a day and it wasn't even a fraction of the way complete.  I am looking at ways that I can improve this.  I am wondering if I put the first n number of plays on their own thread and run it if I can improve the calculation time significantly?
I know if theory it should cut the computation time to 1/n of the original time if there are n threads splitting the work, but will this actually work or will the threads just fight for resources?

Comment: I was about to comment a lot when I realized that this belongs on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Look up dynamic programming. There's no way you can enumerate them all. You need to find a way to break down the problem.

Comment: A first step would be: find all of the connect4 final positions. Count how many different order there exist to reach each final position. This problem is MUCH easier, but is still WAY too complex, so you need to break it down further.